# link_to 'Destroy', [comment.article, comment],

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

In http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html with rails-5.0.2 and Ruby 2.4.1

The guides use

```
[comment.article, comment]
```

Which I like to learn of how to use it, What the meaning of this.
I just don't understand and can not find any document.

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

instead of

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', article_comment_path,
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

which is not work (including article_comment_path(comment)
error shown:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#destroy

<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', article_comment_path(comment)
```

Here routes

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
    article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
                root GET    /                                                 articles#index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's short for a nested route in Rails.  When you provide link_to an array like that, it will translate into a URL such as: /articles/1/comments/2.  Most just use the route helpers however since they're more explicit (ie. `article_comment_path(article_id: @article.id, id: @comment.id)`

Post your controller code for the destroy method as well as any errors you're getting since you have the right routes setup.

Comment: If I use article_comment_path(comment) will error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#destroy

Comment: My Question is the meaning of [comment.article, comment] in the guide.

Comment: I had the same question and came across your query. But I figured it out.
 [comment.article, comment] is just a Rails shorthand you can use when you have a link with a nested route. So just a convenience. With a nested route you need the id of the parent record (the article id found with comment.article) and the child record (comment id). To be more explicit then include the path and put the parameters in parentheses not square brackets like this - article_comment_path(comment.article, comment). And to be really explicit use the path in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see if display <%= [comment.article, comment] %>
It shown

```
[#<Article id: 1, title: "Title of next", text: "sdfsf", created_at: "2017-04-19 01:43:39", updated_at: "2017-04-19 01:43:39">, #<Comment id: 15, commenter: "sdfdsf", body: "sfsdfsd", article_id: 1, created_at: "2017-04-19 02:50:39", updated_at: "2017-04-19 02:50:39">]
```

I must assume that the Rails-5.0.2 known what to do by pick each id 
and pick the proper route for destroy.

I really can not get the better logic behind this.

Ok Back to use guide line from routes

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_comment_path(@article,comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Well This one work perfect! So I stick with this one.